# Multiple custom controls that use mouseMoved in one window

Tags: cocoa, events, controls, mouse

At first I had one window with my custom control. To get it to accept the mouse moved events I simply put in it's awakeFromNib:

Code:

[[self window] makeFirstResponder:self];
[[self window] setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];

Now I'm doing something with four of them in the same window, and this doesn't work so pretty anymore. First off, I took them out of the control's awakeFromNib and decided I'd use my appController to manage it i.e. [window makeFirstResponder:View]

My question is, how do I manage four of these in the same view if I want each one to respond to mouse moved events? Right now, I've told the window to respond to mouseMoved events but none of the views are responding to mouseMoved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need to override -acceptsFirstResponder to return YES.

```
    #pragma mark NSResponder Overrides
    - (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
    {
    return YES;
    }
```

-mouseMoved events are expensive so I turn off mouse moved events when my control's -mouseExited message is called and I turn it on in -mouseEntered.

```
    - (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [[self window] setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
    [[self window] makeFirstResponder:self];
}

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
...
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [[self window] setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:NO];
}
```

I quickly tested this in my custom control application.  I duplicated the control several times in the nib file and it worked as expected.

You may also need:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[self window] setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
    [self addTrackingRect:[self bounds] owner:self userData:NULL assumeInside:YES];
}
```

I don't think the -setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents is necessary, but I'm pretty sure the tracking rect code is.  You may also need to experiment with the value of the assumeInside: parameter, but that is documented.

Comment: I added mouseEntered: and mouseExited: and implemented them as above, but it's not calling the methods (NSLog within is not displaying). Also, what does #pragma mark NSResponder Overrides mean

Comment: I updated the answer for a bit that I forgot. 

The '#pragma mark' is a directive that XCode parses and adds an item to the function popup menu to help find different places in your code.  It is completely ignored by the compiler.

Using a dash(-) as the string will put a separator item in the menu.